# Why is my T-SQL stored procedure not executing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My table structure is as follows:

**GLPERIOD**:

```
 periodid     char
 strtdate     datetime
 closdate     datetime
 fiscalyr     char
```

**GLPOST**:

```
 postdate     datetime
 account      char
 amount       money
```

With this in mind, the following stored procedure, which has parameters defined to be of identical type to what the table columns require, returns nothing when called.

```
PROCEDURE MonthlyActual 
    @P2 CHAR, @P3 CHAR, @P4 CHAR
    SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM GLPOST 
    WHERE account = @P2
      AND postdate BETWEEN (SELECT strtdate 
                            FROM GLPERIOD 
                            WHERE periodid = @P3 AND fiscalyr = @P4) AND 
                           (SELECT closedate 
                            FROM GLPERIOD 
                            WHERE periodid = @P3 AND fiscalyr = @P4)
    GROUP BY   
        account
```

I try calling it like this:

```
MonthlyActual @P2 = '51080-000', @P3 = 1, @P4 = 2018

MonthlyActual @P2 = '51080-000', @P3 = '1', @P4 = '2018'
```

...and get nothing. Yet if I hard-code these values, the code runs perfectly.
What am I doing wrong?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio on Windows Server.

Comment: MonthlyActual @P2 = '51080-000', P3 = '1', P4 = '2018' ?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Also returns nothing. I will update OP accordingly

Comment: and if you post the entire stored procedure ?

Comment: `closdate` vs. `closedate`   Is that typo just in your posting here or also in your code?

Comment: Does it return an error?  Please show the actual procedure code.

Comment: @OleEHDufour forgot to show the parameters and types, adjusted

Comment: @GordonLinoff it does not return any errors, it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: Run the two inner queries and see what you get back for results. If one or both are null, BETWEEN won't work.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Parameters of type `CHAR` are ***ONE CHARACTER*** in length! Typically not what you want - **specify a reasonable length!** or better yet: since those all seems to be **numerical** values - use `INT` or `DECIMAL` instead of converting everything to strings!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that though `periodid` and `fiscalyr` are of `char` data type, passing them `char` values gave no results - because they were not trimmed. Though `periodid` and `fiscalyr` would only ever hold integers, the fact that the database was designed some 20 years ago also meant mediocre habits were in play. Specifically, the equality of `periodid = '1'` never went through because it was stored as ' 1'.

Setting the checks to `WHERE LTRIM( RTRIM( periodid ) ) = LTRIM( RTRIM( @P3 ) )` resolved the issue.

Comment: You could simply use [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to handle both ends of the string. You may want to learn about making the `WHERE` clause [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that it can benefit from indexes. If you pad the "constant" side of the comparison so that you don't need to apply a function to the column value then the query optimizer could use an index rather than [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) processing.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to guess that your stored procedure looks like this:

```
create stored procedure MonthlyActual (
    @p2 char,
    @p3 char,
    @p4 char
)
```

If so, the problem is simple.  The declarations are for a single character.  Change them to more reasonable types:

```
create stored procedure MonthlyActual (
    @account varchar(255),
    @periodid varchar(255),
    @year varchar(255)
)
```

I also recommend renaming the parameters so the code makes more sense.

Moral?  In SQL Server *always* use lengths with `char()` and related types.  The default length varies by context and often introduces hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested, but still do not see results when I try to call the procedure. I get (no column name) in SQL Management Studio, yet get a numeric result when I hard-code the values.

Answer (score 3):

First move your two dates for the `between` into separate statements:

```
Declare @StartDate as datetime
Declare @EndDate as datetime

Set @StartDate = SELECT strtdate FROM GLPERIOD WHERE periodid = @P3 AND fiscalyr = @P4
Set @EndDate = SELECT closdate FROM GLPERIOD WHERE periodid = @P3 AND fiscalyr = @P4

SELECT 
     SUM(amount) 
FROM 
     GLPOST 
WHERE 
     account = @P2 
     AND postdate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
GROUP BY 
     account
```

Next comment out the between statement and see if it returns data. If so then you know the problem is with the date data